# error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: shared-library

I've recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 and tried to execute an application but got the following error message:

*error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I've searched previous posts and the solution to this problem was:

sudo apt-get install libgfortran3

However, when trying this, the following error message appeared:

*Reading package lists... Done*

*Building dependency tree*

*Reading state information... Done*

*E: Unable to locate package libgfortran3*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vinny

Comment: I had to manually install the libgfortran3 (6.4.0-17ubuntu1) and gcc-6-base (6.4.0-17ubuntu1) packages.  It works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good you got it working, but as of the time of this post I see different/newer versions for Ubuntu disco (19.04) `6.5.0-2ubuntu1` vs `6.4.0-17ubuntu1` for Ubuntu bionic (18.04). The version you have, Eoan Ermine (19.10), probably does not have it yet which is why you got the error doing `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`.

You may also try using the libraries from 19.04 here https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libgfortran3

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the newer versions for Ubuntu disco, much appreciated!